# Использование "быстрее" в значении "скорее"

Tags: выбор-слов, история

Откуда пошло использование слова "быстрее" всего в значении "скорее (всего)"?

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_671

Норма явно не литературная, однако достаточно часто сталкиваюсь. Ну вот [для примера сегодняшний случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/807848/213987).

А когда фиксируется первое употребление? Это как-то от иностранцев пришло, которые не чувствуют разницы? Или это какой-то армейский юмор, как [предположили здесь](https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/3361615.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще 9 лет назад спрашивали, можно ли так говорить: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/21855408

Значит, **это сленговое выражение появилось еще тогда**, но, разумеется, оно в значении вводного слова **не нормируется.** В словаре "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" даже делается формальная замена ***скорее всего/быстрее всего***, чтобы различить вводное слово и наречие.

Обычно сленг характерен для молодежной среды со своей обычной функцией —  придать **экспрессивное значение нейтральному слову**  для своеобразной выразительности речи.

Comment: Возможно кто-то когда-то и пошутил, а теперь молодежь повторяет это не задумываясь. Относиться к этому как к сленгу? По-моему, "носители" сленга  должны понимать, что это сленг, а если не понимают — то это уже безграмотность, ставшая нормой.

Comment: Сленг при желании всегда можно назвать безграмотностью, это же отклонение от нормы. Но помните, как Сатин у Горького говорит, что слова ему надоели, потому что он слышал их тысячу раз. Поэтому молодежь и экспериментирует: если наречия сходны по значению, то почему бы не сделать и вводные слова синонимами. Звучит свежо и оригинально, но только пока многие не станут так говорить. А потом словечко, вероятно, уйдет из речи.

Comment: Я еще раз повторю. Граница, по-моему, пролегает там, где человек (или социальная группа) перестает отдавать себе отчет, что он экспериментирует, выходит за рамки словарной нормы.

Comment: Если судить по приведенному примеру ("тут быстрее SCRUM-мастер"), то эти-то люди отдают себе отчет,  на каком языке они говорят и в какой ситуации это уместно. Сленг существовал и будет существовать, это объективное языковое явление. Поэтому не имеет смысла его осуждать, возмущаться и бороться с ним.

Comment: Если с этим не бороться, то следующим шагом станет "шустрее всего", со временем это получит распространение в теледебатах, и закончится всё так же, как это произошло с употреблением выражения "в том числе", которое телевидением в считанные годы превращено в неделимый штамп (осталось косноязычие, возникшее из речи людей с ограниченным словарным запасом, зафиксировать как норму).

Comment: А вот психологи говорят, что борьба   успешной не бывает, например, надо не бороться против войны, а укреплять мир. И здесь также: сленговое слово само исчезнет, если с ним не бороться, а учиться говорить  красиво, правильно и выразительно, а не серо и скучно.. А кстати, что у нас с выражением "в том числе", кому оно помешало? Кажется, оно давно применяется: «Путешественники ничего не потеряли, но все решительно, в том числе и спички, промокли насквозь» (В. Арсеньев).